# cloning a div is also cloning text values

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I need the cloned element's value blank.

The code below works good, but it's cloning the values; cant figure out how to stop that.

```
var Move =  {

    copy    :   function(e, target) { 
                var eId     = $(e);
                var copyE   = eId.cloneNode(true);
                var cLength = copyE.childNodes.length -1;
                copyE.id    = e+'-copy';

                for(var i = 0; cLength >= i;  i++) {
                    if(copyE.childNodes[i].id) {
                    var cNode   = copyE.childNodes[i];
                    var firstId = cNode.id;
                    cNode.value = '';
                    cNode.id    = firstId+'-copy'; }
                }

                $('txtWoundCareLocation').value="";
                $(target).appendChild(copyE);
                },
    element :   function(e, target, type)   {
                var eId =   $(e);
                if(type == 'move') { $(target).appendChild(eId); }

                else if(type == 'copy')     { 
                    this.copy(e, target);
                }
                }
}
```

Comment: So, what's the purpose of this code?

Comment: clone a div, with all the child elements

Comment: But lose the contents of each child element?

Comment: yes, trying to clone blank elements

Answer (score 0):

<strike>[eId.cloneNode(true) returns an jQuery object](http://docs.jquery.com/Clone), not a HTMLNode. Thus `copyE` contains a jQuery object not an HTMLNode. You are using it like an HTMLNode however. This should introduce problems.</strike>

Also, setting value on a jQuery object (as in `$('txtWoundCareLocation').value=""`) will not alter the HTMLNode value. Instead, you should call the `jQuery.val` method to unset the HTMLNode value: `$('txtWoundCareLocation').val('');`

I thought this was about jQuery. I'm not into prototype, sorry.

Comment: This is prototype js not jQuery, I wish it was jQ

Comment: the $('txtWoundCareLocation').val(''); doesnt work with prototype, but $('txtWoundCareLocation').value=''; did, however that just removes the original text, which I don't want. I need the copies blank

Answer (score 0):

Put this at the end of copy:

```
$(cnode.id).value="";
```